# Ler linha a linha de um arquivo e armazenar em strings diferentes em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade  e me deparei com seguinte problema: preciso ler um arquivo .TXT (que é uma lista de mercadorias) e atribuir cada linha a um array diferente.

Estou usando o fgets para ler o arquivo inteiro, mas não sei como transferir os dados para um vetor.

```
 while(fgets(lista, 10000, arquivo) != NULL)
```

E o tipo de dados é o seguinte:

```
31366
CASTANHA CAJU W1/W2 GRAN.KG
969
78
RN
108381
VIN.CHI.TIERRAS CHILE SAUV.BLAN.CLA750ML
842
28
MA
```

E o armazenamento seria feito primeiro valor o numero do produto, segundo nome....  e se repetindo a cada 5 linhas de código.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Sua intenção no caso é criar uma matriz, onde cada linha corresponde a um produto, com uma coluna para cada característica?

Comment: Não, eu quero ler a primeira linha ( que é o valor do codigo do produto ) e atribuir a um vetor, ler a segunda e atribuir a outro vetor, de forma que depois eu consiga usar os dados desses vetores individualmente. Exemplo fazer uma função para ler em ordem alfabetica os nomes dos produtos

Comment: no caso vc teria 5 vetores, um para cada característica.

Comment: isso, seria exatamente o que preciso

Answer (score 0):

pode usar um contador e usar o %5 (total de vetores que vc tem) e usar um algo como

```
int i =0;
while ( fgets(linha ,1000 , arq ) != NULL ){
    if (i%5 == 0 ){
        strcpy(vetor0[i/5], linha);
    }
    else if (i%5 == 1){
        strcpy(vetor1[i/5], linha);
    }
    else if (i%5 == 2){
        strcpy(vetor2[i/5], linha);
    }
    else if (i%5 == 3){
        strcpy(vetor3[i/5], linha);
    }
    else if (i%5 == 4){
        strcpy(vetor4[i/5], linha);
    }
    i++;
}
```

mas se usar uma matriz com cada linha sendo um das características do produto, ficar ate mais simples

```
int i =0;
char matriz[5][100][100];
while ( fgets(linha ,1000 , arq ) != NULL ){
    strcpy(matriz[i%5][i/5], linha);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
seria melhor você pegar uma linha de cada vez , e armazenar em uma matriz de 
string que na linguagem c é conhecida como matriz de char , e poderia ser   
assim  :

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // para usar scanf e outras funcoes no visual studio
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char str[20][100];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("mercadorias.txt", "r");
    while ( fgets(str[i] , sizeof(str[i]) , f ) != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas no caso não resolveria meu problema,  por que eu preciso ler a primeira linha ( que é o valor do código do produto ) e atribuir a um vetor, ler a segunda e atribuir a outro vetor, de forma que depois eu consiga usar os dados desses vetores individualmente. No caso precisaria de 5 vetores diferentes

Comment: oras , bastas pegar cada linha da Matriz e AtribuiR no vetor Que você Quer , e você pode ver que na linha zero da matriz está a primeira linha do arquivo e assim sucessivamente ,,, ....